# Reference return and rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't get this snippet of code that's in a book :

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::get(Identifier id)
{
    auto found = mResourceMap.find(id);
    assert(found != mResourceMap.end());

    return *found->second;
}
```

Why are we dereferencing variable found when it's a normal iterator and not a pointer? Then it's accessed as if we had something like int obj = new Obj(); &obj->someVar;

The cpp reference at this page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ 
says you can dereference an iterator as an rvalue.

I started reading this page http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

It's a good article, but it's a bit dense, anyone can clarify this in the context of the sample code I have provided?

Comment: `found->second` returns `Resource*` and `*` is dereferencing that in order to return a reference.

Comment: "says you can dereference an iterator as an rvalue." - That's for input iterators. Directly below that, for output iterators, it says "Can be dereferenced as an lvalue (only for mutable iterator types)". I'm almost certain your iterator type is both an input and an output iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*found->second` is dereferencing the pointer returned by `found->second`.  The `->` operator has higher precedence than `*` (See [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for a complete listing), so the statement is effectively the same as `*(found->second)`, not as `(*found)->second` like you are thinking of.